# Получить из списка нужный элемент с учетом нулевого индекса

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно получить нужный элемент списка с учетом его первым индексом, к примеру у нас есть такой список:

```
listdata = [['ams', 1, 98],['online', 1, '22 billion'],['ingame', 1, '10 million']]
```

Как получить нужный элемент по ключевому названию, это всегда нулевый индекс к примеру мы хотим получить элемент с названием ams, как это можно сделать?

Comment: `next(item for item in listdata if item[0] == 'ams')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно в лоб:

```
listdata = [['ams', 1, 98],['online', 1, '22 billion'],['ingame', 1, '10 million']]

key = 'online'
res = None
for obj in listdata:
    if key in obj:
        res = obj
        break

print(res)
```

хотя как я понимаю, надо искать только среди первых элементов ключ, а не среди всех значений?

тогда так к примеру:

```
key = 'online'
res = [obj for obj in listdata if obj[0] == key]
res = None if res == [] else res[0]
```

А вот так можно сделать в 1 строчку:

```
res = ([obj for obj in listdata if obj[0] == key] or [None])[0]
```

Comment: Нужно искать среди всех элементов, но проверяя только 0 индекс, тк как это всегда название элемента.

Comment: тогда так как привел в конце ответа?

Comment: да спасибо большое

Comment: нашел интересный вариант в 1 строчку :) чтобы не делать дополнительные проверки